# Is there any danger in not sanitizing user-inputted POST arguments for cURL?

Tags: php, curl

So I'm using my PHP application as a proxy to log people in to a variety of services.  For some of these services, I have no idea what the actual constraints are for their usernames and passwords so I'm reluctant to sanitize the user input.

Do I have anything to worry about with passing in the user input as the values for the applicable "user_name" and "password" keys in my POST arguments array as used with the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option?

Is there anything else I can do to make things a little safer without accidentally invalidating logins?

Comment: Since your app is a proxy to external sites, you don't need to validate passed data. It is duty for that sites

Comment: There's always a danger in never sanitizing user inputs. However, since your service acts like a proxy, the services you POST to will take the hit. Either way, those services will probably return errors if something was wrong with the user input.

Comment: Ok, that's more-or-less what I was thinking.  Nothing particular to cURL that would throw it off?  I'm envisioning some kind of crazy memory limitation on POST values that when pushed just right, ends up executing arbitrary code at the end or something.  Just want to be careful.

Comment: If you keep `post_max_size` within reasonable limits, you're good to go. Imagine your task as being a gas pipe - you want to ensure that you're solid and stable without any cracks, you transfer as much gas as needed and not more/less, and you can't accidentally blow yourself. Meet these criteria, and let the other side worry about the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you're absolutely sure that:

1. your application is serving only as a proxy
2. you do not do anything with the user input inside **your** app
3. every single one of these services uses it's own way of sanitizing user input and doesn't rely on you for that.

Then you should not have any problems.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that all of those services use their own sanitizing mechanisms, but I sure hope they do.  There's nothing I can do about that though in this case -- it's just a requirement for the app.  I meet 1 and 2 though.

Comment: Then it depends on how these services think of you. Do they **trust you** with providing valid input, or they simply require any kind of input? If they trust you, it's your responsibility to provide them with safe and valid input. Otherwise, you're just a proxy - it's not your job to do that, and you probably shouldn't.

Comment: Oh no, they don't trust me at all.  I'm just joe schmoe sending them garbage as far as they're concerned.